# Django: join, keep one of two columns, then order by that

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have two Django models, roughly summarized by:

```
class Thing(Model):
    date_created = DateTimeField()

class ThingDateOverride(Model):
    thing    = ForeignKey(Thing)
    category = ForeignKey(Category)
    override = DateTimeField()
```

What I want to do is produce a list of `Things` for a given a `Category` sorted by the appropriate `ThingDateOverride` `override` field, or the `Thing`'s `date_created` if no such override exists.

In other words:

- For each `Thing` in the `QuerySet`, keep either `Thing.date_created` or the `override` if an appropriate `ThingDateOverride` exists for that `Thing`/`Category` pair.
- Order the `Thing` set by the resulting timestamp.

I can pull this off in SQL, but I'd rather avoid writing possibly engine-specific code. I'm currently implementing the logic around the ORM (in pure python), but I would like the database to handle this.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ok, that category is stored in `ThingDateOverride`? If yes, then `Thing` object doesn't have category without override object.

I assumed that `ThingDateOverride` object exists for every `Thing` object (so category is assigned to every `Thing` object). `override` field can be NULL, then `date_created` object will be used to sort things. Then this code should sort by `override` if it exists, or by `date_created` if doesn't:

```
Thing.objects.filter(thingdateoverride__category=category).extra(select={'d': 'if(override, override, date_created)'}).order_by('d')
```

The idea is to use `extra` and select `override` field if it exists, or `date_created` if doesn't as another column, and then sort by that column.

Note: this code works only because `override` and `date_created` fields have different names, so they could be distinguished. Otherwise MySQL will return error, something like "field name is ambiguous", and need to add table names.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, probably it won't work in all cases, but it's working option and it could be tweaked if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Thing`, you should start by that model and use  [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships):

```
Thing.objects.filter(thingdateoverride__category=category).order_by("thingdateoverride__override", "date_created")
```

Comment: That won't work. First it'll sort by `override` and then by `date_created`. So first `Thing` objects with no `override` will be returned (sorted by `date_created`), and then `Thing` objects with `override` (sorted by `override`). It's not the same as "override OR date_created".

Comment: @trez what demalexx said :P Thanks, though!